# use python or bash to copy audio files by time stamp to new folder

Tags: python, linux, bash, audio

Hello I have been trying to figure a way to restore our audio files in our archive server. They are scattered in several sub directories in this server and the naming schema is some what varied. They are mostly in the "/media/recordings" directory.

Here are a few examples of what i am talking about.

```
YYYY_XXX) XXX-XXXX_20151125-094056_10931-all
YYYYYYY_XXX-XXX-XXXX _20151013-094634_10896-all
YYYY_(XXX) XXX-XXXX_20151116-120923_10215-all
YYYYY_ XXXXXXXXXX_20160307-152940_11033-all
```

The audio files are both .wav and .mp3's and they all have a time stamp in the file name that i have tried to isolate and use as the model to cut in the YYYY/MM/DD to create sub directories. I have read some others trying to organize there files with bash and have tried to adapt something to work and can not seem to come up with a working script. Help please.

I would like to copy this files from /media/recordings/MP3 and ORIG with the exclusion of /media/recording/ORIG/sorted to  "/media/recordings/ORIG/sorted" as the destination location. And sort these files by the year/month/day sub directories.

This is an older centos machine with python 2.6.6. i have tried to adapt something that can go to a dir and recursively navigate the sub directories but my time has been limited to resolve this matter any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this SO posting on copying files of specific extension from multiple folders to single folder. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31859887/copy-specific-files-from-multiple-directories-using-python

Comment: Your question is not clear. You do not show any example of a MP3 or WAV file name. What are your `YYYY_XXX) XXX-XXXX_20151125-094056_10931-all`? Files? Directories? What new names do you want for your files, once they are moved in YYYY/MM/DD directories? Please try to clearly explain what you have and what you want.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].

Comment: I removed the .mp3 or .wav of of the file name. each one could be a wav or a mp3. Sorry for having no examples my general path of making this is to wipe the slate clean if i hit a dead end. to start with fresh out look. I just went through 2 cycles of them and removed all examples to start fresh. and am starting to run short on time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you need:

```sh
#!/bin/bash 
source_dir="/media/recordings"
dest_dir="/media/recordings/ORIG/sorted"
for file in ${source_dir}/{MP3,ORIG}/*; do
    etime=$(stat -c %Y "$file")
    fdate=$(date -d @$etime +"%Y-%m-%d")
    if [[ ! -d "$dest_dir/$fdate" ]]; then
        mkdir "$dest_dir/$fdate"
        mv "$file" "$dest_dir/$fdate"
    else
        mv "$file" "$dest_dir/$fdate"
    fi
done
```

The script will search for all files in source_dir/MP3 and ORIG directories, and move them in dest_dir/YYYY-MM-DD location sorted by a date. The character / is not allowed in file and directory names.

```
$ tree media/recordings/ORIG/sorted
├── 2014-10-30
│   └── song.mp3
├── 2015-11-07
│   └── song.wav
├── 2015-11-12
│   └── another_song.mp3
├── 2017-07-11
│   └── another_song.wav
├── 2017-09-06
│   ├── song-1.mp3
│   ├── song-2.wav
│   └── song-3.mp3
```

Comment: Thanks for getting back with me on this. I altered this a little to copy and created a a sub folder for each audio. something like this 2014/12/02. I have run the script and it did not read the time stamp right i was getting multiple days in the same folder. Here is what i have so far.

Comment: #!/bin/bash
source_dir="/media/recordings/"
dest_dir="/media/recordings/ORIG/sorted"
for file in ${source_dir}/{MP3,ORIG}/*; do
    etime=$(stat -c %Y "$file")
    fdate=$(date -d @$etime +"%Y/%m/%d")
    if [[ ! -d "$dest_dir/$fdate" ]]; then
        mkdir -v -p "$dest_dir/$fdate"
        cp "$file" "$dest_dir/$fdate"
    else
        cp "$file" "$dest_dir/$fdate"
    fi
done

Comment: sorry this is my second post here and i can not seem to get the format to look like yours.